# Navigation Drawer very lag

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to open the Navigation Drawer, but the drawer is too lag. However I open Google play store is normal. How can I improve this?

This is my layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/hhome1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermunu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my code
I think it cause lag in this part

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerlayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I tried to simplify this`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new HomeFrament()).commit();` but I don't know why it's not work

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerlayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFrament()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_control:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ControlFrament()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SettingsFrament()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_tandh:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new TandHFrament()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new LogoutFrament()).commit();
            break;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid this lag?

Comment: You seem to have left out code.

Comment: Oops! I have already re-edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try to change the images which you used in navigation drawer (in
>   header)
>
> or once remove background image then see :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/hhome1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: I try to use this one :
`<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
`
It works!  I'll change my background image and try once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simultaneously 2 operation are working. 1 is closing the drawer and 2 is fragment transaction.

If you have checked google play store or gmail. When you click navigation drawer menu item the first thing that work is to remove the visibilty of the content in main screen by making alpha to 0. Then fragment transaction is done on after successfully closing the drawer.

You setup the ActionBarDrawerToggle to listen onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpened callbacks.

Comment: Thx! So remove the visibilty is setup in the ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: onNavItemSelected callback you will hide the main content and get the selected item. And in onDrawerClosed you will have to make the fragment transition